# C# XmlReader парсинг и редактирование

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

Делаю библиотеку классов для работы с XML файлами, использую для этого методы XmlReader. И поскольку нашёл не так много информации, то столкнулся с проблемой чтения дочерних тегов. Например, есть XML файл со следующим содержимым:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<library>
    <book id="1">
        <name>book1<name>
        <price currency="$">15</price>
    <book>
</library>
```

Здесь, я понимаю как получить доступ к содержимому тега `<book>`

```
XmlReader document = XmlReader.Create(path);
while(document.Read())
{
    if(document.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && document.Name == "book")
    {
        Console.Write(document.ReadInnerXml());//Выведет содержимое тега <book>
    }
}
```

Но у него есть ещё 2 дочерних тега, и мне нужно получить их содержимое, и несмотря на то, что я пролистал методы XmlReader на сайте майкрософт, ничего конкретного я не нашёл. Если такого метода нет, то можно ли при помощи данных методов как-то реализовать подобное?
И ещё вопрос: можно ли в XmlReader как-то добавлять и удалять данные в XML файлах? Если да, то как?

Comment: Вероятно там должна быть какая-то [рекурсивная обработка](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=net-7.0#navigating-through-nodes) посмотрите тут метод [ReadSubtree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readsubtree?view=net-7.0)   , понятное дело уровень вложенности может быть условно любой. Менять тоже можно, по сути это пересоздание существующего файла на основе измененной структуры. И еще один полезный метод [ReadInnerXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.readinnerxml?view=net-7.0)

Comment: "Reader" - означает "Читатель". Он предназначен именно для чтения. Для записи используйте класс XmlWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш XML файл имеет неправильный формат (not well-formed). Несоответствие закрывающих тегов. Я должен был исправить это в первую очередь.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<library>
    <book id="1">
        <name>book1</name>
        <price currency="$">15</price>
    </book>
</library>
```

Лучше использовать **LINQ to XML** API для XML-файлов среднего размера. Он доступен в .Net Framework с 2007 года.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string filePath = @"e:\Temp\input.xml";
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    XElement book = xdoc.Descendants("book")
        .Where(v => v.Attribute("id")?.Value == "1").FirstOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine("name='{0}', price='{1}'",
       book.Element("name")?.Value, 
       book.Element("price")?.Value);
}
```

**Результат**

```
name='book1', price='15'
```